# Windows 7 automatic update installation: How to see progress or cancel/postpone

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Sometimes when I reboot my Win7 machine, I get a prompt saying "Please do not power off or unplug your machine. Installing update 1 of N..." (where N is a variable). I have two questions:

1. Is there any way to monitor the progress of the installation process? (Of course, you can observe the "1" change to "2, 3, ...", but are there other options?)
2. Is there any way to influence (cancel, postpone, whatever...) the installation process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I have ever found, this is why I disable full automatic updates, I use the setting "Download Updates but let me choose whether to install them"

.
[image]